# Expression for the entries of the inverse of a block tri-diagonal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request

Specifically I am interested in the entries of the inverse of

$$
\mathcal{A}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A & B & & \\
    B & \ddots & \ddots & \\
      & \ddots & & B  \\
      &        & B & A \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$$

where $B$ and $A$ are square invertable matrices. I am going though the algebra by trying to find $Z$ such that $\mathcal{A}Z = \mathbb{I}$.

This algebra is very tedious and so I was wondering if such an expression already exists for such a matrix.

Comment: I can find formulas for the inverse when A and B are 1x1 blocks but I have not found a great deal of information on the inverse of the non-trivial blocked counterpart.

Comment: Would this help? https://di.ku.dk/forskning/Publikationer/tekniske_rapporter/2010/Inversion-of-Block-Tridiagonal-Matrices.pdf/

Comment: I am interested in an expression for the inverse and not numerically calculating it. Unless the answer is in that document and I scrolled past it...